# Why does Harry think burying someone with magic is not proper?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1* (2010), Harry insists that Hermoine and Ron bury Dobby without using magic:

> Harry: I want to bury him. Properly. Without magic.

Why does Harry think burying someone with magic is not proper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Burying him with the use of magic would be - comparatively - effortless.

Harry considers a burial undertaken with manual effort to represent more significant a final gesture of respect for Dobby than merely waving a wand and then skipping away.

Answer (score 6):

### He does it as a tribute to Dobby

This is better explained in the books:

> “I want to do it properly,” were the first words of which Harry was fully conscious of speaking. “Not by magic. Have you got a spade?” And shortly afterward he had set to work, alone, digging the grave in the place that Bill had shown him at the end of the garden, between bushes. He dug with a kind of fury, **relishing the manual work, glorying in the non-magic of it, for every drop of his sweat and every blister felt like a gift to the elf who had saved their lives**.
>
> <sub>*(The Wandmaker, The Deathly Hallows)*</sub>